# Show one <div> and hide another

Tags: jquery, html

I have two `<div>` elements:

```
<div id="hidden"> 

<div id="hideitem">
<input id="item5" type="radio" class="item" name="item" value="gen"/>General Function
</div>
```

I set `<div id="hidden">` to `display:none`.  I want it to show when the radio button is clicked:

```
$("#item5").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").show();
}
```

But how can I hide `<div id="hideitem">` after `<div id="hidden">` is shown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most `jQuery fx methods`, `.show()` has a optional parameter where you can serve a `callback function`. The function you pass there is executed after the `fx effect` has finished.

```
$('#hidden').show('fast', function(){
   $('#hideitem').hide();
});
```

That would pass an `anonymous function` as parameter, which is called after the effect. It just hides the `#hideitem` object then.
You'll notice that I've added an additional parameter `'fast'`. That is the duration jQuery uses to execute the fadeout (can also be a number in ms). It really only makes sense to use it like this, because otherwise, `.show()` will just set the `display` property to `block`. Without a duration we have no delay. So a callback function for that would get invoked immediately.

If you want to show and hide that elements simultaneously just call both

```
$('#hidden').show();
$('#hideitem').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can just do something like this:

```
$("#item5").click(function(){

                         $("#hidden").show();
                         $("#hideitem").hide();
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just hide it:

```
$("#item5").click(function(){
  $("#hidden").show();
  $("#hideitem").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this function so that keep switching div's use a toggle statement

```
$('#hidden').toggle('fast', function(){
   $('#hideitem').toggle();
});
```